# Is a Java object with hundreds of methods expensive?

Tags: java, android, object

I have a class like below, with hundreds of methods:

```
public class APIMethods {


public ToView toView;

public APIMethods(ToView toView) {
    this.toView = toView;
}


public static final int SUCCESS = 1;
public static final int ERROR = 0;


public void registerAnonymous(String deviceId, String installRef, final int requestCode) {
    APIInterface apiService =
            RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIInterface.class);
    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
    obj.addProperty("androidId", deviceId);
    obj.addProperty("projectId", 0);
    obj.addProperty("ChannelName", installRef);
    Call<Response<BasicUser>> call = apiService.registerAnonymous("application/json", Utils.getFlavorId(), obj);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Response<BasicUser>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Response<BasicUser>> call, Response<Response<BasicUser>> response) {
            Response<BasicUser> mResponse;
            try {
                mResponse = response.body();
                if (mResponse.getErrorCode() == 0)
                    toView.updateView(requestCode, SUCCESS, mResponse);
                else
                    toView.updateView(requestCode, ERROR, mResponse);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mResponse = new Response<>();
                mResponse.setErrorCode(-1);
                toView.updateView(requestCode, ERROR, mResponse);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PetMarkResponse<BasicUser>> call, Throwable t) {
            Response<BasicUser> numberValidationResponse = new Response<BasicUser>();
            numberValidationResponse.setErrorCode(-1);
            toView.updateView(requestCode, ERROR, numberValidationResponse);
        }
    });
}

///And dozens of such method
}
```

So in my other classes everywhere in my application, I simply instantiate the class and call the method that I want:

```
APIMethods api = new APIMethods(this);
api.registerAnonymous(Utils.getAndroidId(this), BuildConfig.FLAVOR, STATE_REGISTER_ANONYMOUS);
```

My question is how expensive this object (api) is? Note that in each class, a few methods of the object are called.

Comment: If you need all those methods you'll either have a god(dess) class w/ a lot of methods, or a bunch of classes each w/ fewer methods. Which makes the most sense depends entirely on your usecase. That said: a class with "hundreds of methods" is difficult to work with, and it's highly unlikely the methods are all directly related to each other.

Comment: No the methods are definitely independent on each other. They are all api calls like the one I included in the example.

Comment: IMO at the *very* least they should be broken up by broad functionality, e.g., you might have `user` API calls, `content` API calls, and so on. It's also likely there's some additional refactoring to be done.

Comment: Pretty nice idea. But what about performance? Is the current class expensive?

Comment: That’s already been answered. The code will exist somewhere—the issues with this class are usability-related.

Comment: With a class having more than one hundred methods I would seriously doubt the design here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is not expensive at all.

An object contains a pointer to the object's class, and the methods are stored with the class. Essentially, the methods are all shared. An object of a class with no methods and an object of a class with 10000 methods are the same size (assuming everything else is equal).

The situation would be different if you had 100 fields instead of 100 methods.

You may want to think about if having hundreds of methods in a single class is a good idea. Is the code easy to understand and maintain? Is this an example of the "God object" anti pattern? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object

Comment: Yes, the code is easy to understand because the methods are quite independent. Each method may be call from multiple classes. That's why I gathered them up in one place, for ease of use.

Comment: @Saj I would disagree precisely *because* they're independent. Unrelated code shouldn't be in close proximity. Not to mention navigating a file with hundreds and hundreds of lines is messy.

Comment: What about breaking them into smaller topic based classes? Like UserAPI, LoginAPI etc? As Dave suggests?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a classic example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your actual problem is how to make the code readable, but you're actually asking about whether a class with hundreds of methods is expensive.

It being expensive is the least of your concerns - you should be more worried about maintenance. There's no reason at all that any class should ever be that large, especially if you have a lot of independent methods and each class is only calling a few of them. This will make the class very hard to understand - having them all in one place will *not* improve the situation.

Some of the comments have already pointed this out, but you should, at a minimum, break this up topically.

Even better, refactor this to the Strategy pattern and use a Factory to pick which one to use. That will meet your goal of ease of use while avoiding the problem of having hundreds of unrelated methods in one place.

Answer (score -1):

Try to define a Cohesive class, untill and unless the methods are written relevant to the class and it defines its purpose.

Below link describe the importance of methods for a class:

https://www.decodejava.com/coupling-cohesion-java.htm

Comment: This doesn't address the question, as such it is a comment.